# Different result on inequality to prove Riemann-Lebesgue lemma

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> **Riemann-Lebesgue lemma**. Assume $h(x)$ is continuous on $(-\pi,\pi]$. Then
>
> $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}h(x)\sin(nx)\mathrm dx\to 0\text{ and }\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}h(x)\cos(nx)\mathrm dx\to 0$$
>
> as $n\to\infty$.

In order to prove this I must show an inequality:

> Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta>0$ such that when $|x-y|<\delta$ it implies that $|h(x)-h(y)|<\epsilon/2$. The period of $\sin(nx)$ is $2\pi/n$, so choose $N$ large enough such that $\pi/n<\delta$ when $n\ge N$.
>
> Now consider an interval $[a,b]$ of length $2\pi/n$. Then show that
>
> $$\left|\int_a^b h(x)\sin(nx)\mathrm dx\right|<\epsilon/n$$
>
> and use this fact to complete the proof.

What I did: because there is a complete oscillation of $\sin(nx)$ on this interval then the function inside the integral take the value zero two times, and at least once in each interval of the partition $P=\{a,\frac{a+b}{2},b\}$.

And because $b-a<2\delta$ each interval of the partition have length less than $\delta$ so, at most, any difference between values of $h(x)$ differs in a $\epsilon/2$ quantity.

Because, as I said, in each interval of $P$ the function value zero somewhere then the supremum of each interval is, at most, $\epsilon/2$. Then

$$\left|\int_a^b h(x)\sin(nx)\mathrm dx\right|\le|U(h,P)|<\frac{b-a}{2}\sum_{k=1}^2 \epsilon/2=\frac{\color{red}{\pi}\epsilon}{n}$$

where $U(h,P)$ denotes the Darboux upper sum of $h$ in the partition $P$.

This result is enough to prove that the integral converges to zero when $n\to\infty$, but I dont know how to eliminates the $\pi$ term in my estimation to take the estimation stated in the book.

Then my question: maybe this is a typo in the book? There is a way to eliminate the $\pi$ term? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you have $\pi/n<\delta$ it seems to me that the $\pi$ factor is already 'included' in $n$.