# proving that $|\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\sin(nt)dt| \le \frac{4}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

I've been trying for hours to prove that $|\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\sin(nt)dt| \le \frac{4}{n^2}$ according the following question, with no luck.

The question is:

Given that $f(x)$ has a continuous second derivative in $[0,2\pi]$, $f(0)=f(2\pi)$ and $|f''(x)| \le 1$ for every $x \in [0,2\pi]$. Prove that $|\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\sin(nt)dt| \le \frac{4}{n^2}$ for every natural n.

What I tried to do: I tried to "get to" the second derivative using integration by parts. Since we know that $f(0)=f(2\pi)$, I tried to take an integral from 0 to 1, and from 1 to $2\pi$ and since we know that $|f''(x)| \le 1$, we know that the absolute value will always be a fracture. But I couldn't get to prove that it will always be less than $\frac{4}{n^2}$.

Hope you could help me with it.

Another note, while I researched I saw that similar problems are solved using fourier transformations - this is not a fourier question.

Comment: take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846616/different-result-on-inequality-to-prove-riemann-lebesgue-lemma)

Comment: What about IBP (integration by parts)? recall second derivative of x->sin x is...x->-sin x

Comment: Please note that fourier is a person (Jean-Baptiste Joseph), so it should be Fourier. And *this is not a fourier question* depends on chosen approach. If you plan to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality or some sort of decomposition, this can be perfectly seen as a problem about Hilbert/Sobolev spaces and Fourier series/transforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, we know that:

$$\int\text{f}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{g}\space'\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t=\text{f}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{g}\left(t\right)-\int\text{f}\space'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{g}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\tag1$$

So, when $\text{f}\left(t\right)=\text{f}\left(t\right)$ and $\text{g}\space'\left(t\right)=\sin\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)$, we get:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\text{f}\left(t\right)\cdot\sin\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)\space\text{d}t=\frac{1}{\text{n}}\cdot\left\{\text{f}\left(0\right)-\cos\left(2\pi\cdot\text{n}
\right)\cdot\text{f}\left(2\pi\right)+\int_0^{2\pi}\text{f}\space'\left(t\right)\cdot\cos\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)\space\text{d}t\right\}\tag2$$

Now, we know that $\text{f}\left(0\right)=\text{f}\left(2\pi\right)$ and $\text{n}\in\mathbb{N}^+$, so we get:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\text{f}\left(t\right)\cdot\sin\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)\space\text{d}t=\frac{1}{\text{n}}\cdot\left\{\int_0^{2\pi}\text{f}\space'\left(t\right)\cdot\cos\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)\space\text{d}t\right\}\tag3$$

Using IBP again:

$$\frac{1}{\text{n}}\cdot\left\{\int_0^{2\pi}\text{f}\space'\left(t\right)\cdot\cos\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)\space\text{d}t\right\}=$$
$$\frac{1}{\text{n}}\cdot\left\{\left[\text{f}\space'\left(t\right)\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)}{\text{n}}\right]_0^{2\pi}-\int_0^{2\pi}\text{f}\space''\left(t\right)\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)}{\text{n}}\space\text{d}t\right\}=$$
$$-\frac{1}{\text{n}^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\text{f}\space''\left(t\right)\cdot\sin\left(\text{n}\cdot t\right)\space\text{d}t\tag4$$

Comment: if modulus is applied, then we get $\frac{2 \pi}{n^2} = \frac{6. xx}{n^2}$. how to prove $\frac{4}{n^2}$

Comment: i got there too @anirudhb. either we've done something wrong or we might be missing something

Comment: Note, $\int_0^{2\pi}|\sin(nt)|dt =4$. +1